# What's an example of the backoff field? Is there some way I can simulate it to test appropriate behavior?

Tags: support, rate-limit

In reading about the API [rate limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), the documentation talks about a method responding with an ominous `backoff` field, and states that the client should cease from calling that method for that many seconds.

Is there a dummy method that always returns a `backoff` that I can test against?  Otherwise, what does the `backoff` field come back in the form of?

Regular int?

```
{ ... "backoff": 20}
```

a string to be parsed?

```
{ ... "backoff": "20"}
```

Comment: Related feature request with a possible stopgap in the answer(s): ["Can we have some debug endpoints for testing corner cases?"](http://stackapps.com/q/2905/7653)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the [response wrapper](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) defines the `backoff` field as an integer, so you can expect it to come back in the first form.

I don't believe there's any way to graciously test a backoff response short of actually angering the API (which I'd recommend against).