# Can I ask the API to tell me to back off?

Tags: support, feature-request, api, rate-limit

I'm creating a bot that collects all tags from a given site (and over all sites in the network).  I would obviously like to run this bot in as little time as possible, but I also do not want to overly stress the API with my single application.  As this bot is being written in Lisp, I also want to protect any future users of the code I write from the API's backlash over misuse.

I want to simulate receiving a `backoff` response in the wrapper, but that would necessitate a serious alteration of the code I have to force the issue on a random-ish basis.  Is there any request I can make to the API (or speed/number of requests) that will cause the API to tell me to back off?

Comment: Also a duplicate of ["Can we have some debug endpoints for testing corner cases?"](http://stackapps.com/q/2905/7653) -- see the answer there for a possible stopgap.

Comment: Related: ["Best strategies for calling the API with full throttling support?"](http://stackapps.com/q/3644/7653).

Comment: For what it's worth, waiting about 150ms in between requests seems to work okay, although the `backoff` response can be returned at any interval depending on various factors.